# Instagram api permission review (only got basic)

Tags: instagram-api

I started the Instagram permission review for basic, follower_list and public_content.  To get to the point, doesn't Tinder have to user public_content to connect and share your Instagram photos to your dating profile? because I am doing the same kind of app with same feature but they did not give me public_content.  So can the Instagram photo connect feature be done with just basic permission end-point?

Comment: -Basic permission was approved for me

Answer (score 1):

> So can the Instagram photo connect feature be done with just basic
>   permission end-point?

No. To view other users' media you need `public_content` scope.

Comment: So basically Instagram gives special privilege to Tinder. Their Instagram API rules are not fairly applied equally on all developers. -Just a tad unfair!

Comment: Hard to know what's up with Tinder. They may have been grandfathered in or they may have made some kind of back room deal. Regardless, Instagram's new API policies have nothing to do with fairness. That's for sure. After all, they're owned by Facebook...